# Does Microsoft word have wildcards for return (\r) & new line (\n) like Grep or Regex do?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, grep, find-and-replace

I frequently want to replace multiple consecutive return characters in written documents with a single return character and to use paragraph space (space after) to do the formatting.  Sometimes there are single spaces that need to be caught also. In InDesign the find and replace looks like this:

**Find:** \s*[\s*\r]+

**Replace:** \r

After searching the Word Docs I'm not sure return and new line chars are wildcards that exist in Microsoft Word. (definitely don't exist in Apple Pages).

Answer (score 3):

In Microsoft Word, you can use wildcards to search and replace formatting characters, including return and newline characters. To do this, follow these steps:

Press Ctrl + H to open the Find and Replace dialog.
Click the "More >>" button to expand the dialog and show more options.
Check the "Use wildcards" option.
In the "Find what" field, enter the following expression to match consecutive return characters and/or single spaces:

```
([ ^013]{1,}){2,}
```

Here, ^013 is the code for a return character in Word, and the expression matches one or more return characters or single spaces, repeated two or more times.

In the "Replace with" field, enter the following to replace the matched characters with a single return character:

```
^013
```

Click "Replace All" to replace all instances of consecutive return characters and single spaces with a single return character.
After completing the find and replace, you can adjust the paragraph spacing in your document:

Select the entire document with Ctrl + A.
Right-click on the selected text and choose "Paragraph" from the context menu.
In the "Spacing" section of the Paragraph dialog, set the "After" value to the desired amount of space (measured in points) you want between paragraphs.
Click "OK" to apply the new paragraph spacing.
Unfortunately, Apple Pages does not support wildcards for find and replace. You would need to use another text editor or word processor that supports regular expressions to perform this task in a similar manner.

I found this page useful. https://www.customguide.com/word/how-to-use-wildcards-in-word

Comment: that specific find code doesn't seem to get any hits for me. I can get hits of either space or return with [ ^013] (which is not really the target, it's "(zero or more spaces followed by return) x [2..] that I'm after where [2..] is one of the natural numbers after 1. 

I'm playing around with variations, "^013" should get me there I guess… not sure about the {1,} and {2,} Will have to look up what they do, something to do with repetition I guess.

Comment: `( @^013)^013@`  is the closest i've got so far. the {0,} doesn't seem to work for zero or more spaces for me. I'll have to make one pass to get spaces and another pass without space, just consecutive returns. and keep doing both until all gone.

Comment: for future reference `^|` is the `manual line break` character code (also known in DTP as `soft returns`).

Comment: `[ ^013^|]{2,}` is my best effort, though will also pick up two or more space chars in a row and replace with a return, so if there's a lot of those best to sweep for multiple consecutive space chars and replace with tabs or something else before doing global replace for multiple return/newline/space.